# Play (on Click) wistia video with custom overlay using JS ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, onclicklistener, wistia

Below is the mark-up

```
<div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
  <div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">
      <div id="play-button-overlay-zwflowymel" class="play-button-overlay d-none d-block">
         <img class="custom-wistia-play-button img-fluid " src="/assets/img/VSL-2019-Thumbnail-01.png" width="942" height="530">
      </div>
      <script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/zwflowymel.jsonp" async></script>
      <div id="sp-video_zwflowymel" class="wistia_embed wistia_async_zwflowymel videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;position:relative;width:100%">
         <div class="wistia_swatch" style="height:100%;left:0;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;transition:opacity 200ms;width:100%;">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Below is my ES6 JavaScript attempt:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      loadSVGs();
      document.getElementById("play-button-overlay-zwflowymel").addEventListener('click', () => {
      _wq.push({
      id: 'zwflowymel',
      onReady: function (video) {
      video.play();
    }
   });
   console.log('pressed Play');
  });
```

I am not getting any errors in the console; but video still will not play.

The Wistia API: https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-api seems to only tout jQuery methods to use. I simply want to play the video, that has a custom image overlay, on click, using vanilla JavaScript Es6,

Comment: To get a better answer this question, please show your html and css. Your javascript refers to the div with id `play-button-overlay-zwflowymel` Do you have that div in your code? How is it styled?

Comment: @jimboweb Yes; not sure why that was omitted. The html markup is back.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the event listener **after** the video has been loaded. The `play` method **has** to be user driven. In your example you load the video on a click, but because of the async nature of the video loading the `play()` method will not be seen as *user interaction*.

Quote from the [play method section](https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-api#play) in the Wistia documentation.

> Because of this restriction, you should avoid calling play() within a setTimeout callback or other asynchronous functions like XHR or javascript promises.

Loading the video is probably a `XHR` function.
Try out this example below and let me know if it works.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    loadSVGs();
    _wq.push({ id: 'zwflowymel', onReady: function (video) {

        document.getElementById("play-button-overlay-zwflowymel").addEventListener('click', () => {
            video.play();
            console.log('pressed Play');
        });

    }});
});
```